Check if header has been generated using cmake
Let's say I have two files main.cpp and generate_header.cpp. generate_header.cpp generates a header containing data that main.cpp needs to run. based on this answer, I can use the following code to run generate_header.cpp before building main.cpp:
add_custom_target(run_generate_header 
    COMMAND generate_header
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "generating header"
)

add_dependencies(main_target run_generate_header)

However, as generating the header's content is slow, I would like to generate the header content only if the header is empty.
To achieve this, I thought about using a preprocessor macro HEADER_GENERATED, and check_cxx_symbol_exists to generate the header's content only if the macro is not defined.
check_cxx_symbol_exists(HEADER_GENERATED ${HEADER_PATH} HEADER_GENERATED)

if (NOT HEADER_GENERATED)
   add_dependencies(main_target run_generate_header)
endif()

The problem with this approach is that check_cxx_symbol_exists runs during the configuration stage, not the build stage, so if the header is erased after configuration, it will not be regenerated and the build will fail. Is there a way to check if the header contains data during the build stage? Thanks in advance!


"Is there a way to check if the header contains data during the build stage?" - Not sure what do you want to achieve by such check. E.g., if given check would succeed, you cannot run add_dependencies or other CMake commands, because CMake context doesn't exist during the build stage.

I didn't know that. So if i can't modify my configuration at build time, does this mean that conditional header generation is not a good idea and I should just regenerate the header every time?

This seems cumbersome for large projects though. Are there any good practices for this type of issue?

only if it does not contain data. What does not contain data? What is "it"? generate_header.cpp generates a header containing data that main.cpp needs to run generate_header.cpp compiles into a program named generate_header that can be used to generate a header that main.cpp requires to execute or to compile? Could you explain the dependency chain in more detail?

I don't find your issue itself to be practical. If main.cpp uses some "data", then given data should be defined in any case. And it is up to your project's configuration to decide, whether main.cpp would get these data from the generated header or from the other source.

@KamilCuk "it" is the header. generate_header needs to execute for the header to be generated, and to allow main to be compiled.

@tsyvarev I didn't include details in the question as I thought they were not relevant, but here they are: the "data" is some neural network parameters. Initially, those parameters are stored in an external .bin file. generate_header.cpp takes the parameters from this external file and stores them in a header. Then, main.cpp is linked with the header and compiles in a single executable containing the neural network. I don't really see a better way to do this.

"it" is the header. So you generate header from the header? You generate a header if the header contains any data? Seems like if it doesn't contain any data, it never will. Can you clearly separate generated data from input data? What is the initial state? Can you draw a draw.io graph of dependency?

I would like to generate the header's content (using generate_header.cpp) if the header does not contain any data.

anyways, i'll try to implement your answer, as it seems to solve my issue (however, it is not cross platform)

Added an edit to the answer

Do not use add_custom_target for something that is generated. If something is generated, it's add_custom_command(OUTPUT this_is_generated.h - tell CMake what is generated and where and from what. Usually, you want pairs add_custom_command & add_custom_target. Sole add_custom_target is for executing something, like running a linter or printing file size.

I would like to generate it only if it does not contain data.

So do that. Generate files in cmake current binary dir.
add_custom_command(
    COMMENT "generating header"
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/the_generated_header.h
    COMMAND
        sh -xc
        [=[
        mkdir -vp "$(dirname "$2")"
        if it does contains data; then
            "$1" -o "$2"
        else
            echo > "$2"
        fi
        ]=]
        sh
        $<TARGET_FILE:generate_header>
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/the_generated_header.h
    DEPENDS generate_header 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
add_custom_target(run_generate_header DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/the_generated_header.h)

add_dependencies(main_target run_generate_header)
target_include_directries(main_target PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen)


however, it is not cross platform

To be crossplatform, you would write the sh script in cmake. So create a file like:
# script.cmake
# check if the file exists in cmake
execute_process(${ARGV1} -o ${ARGV2})
# etc

Then you would call this cmake script from cmake:
add_custom_command(
   COMMAND cmake -P ./script.cmake 
    $<TARGET_FILE:generate_header>
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/the_generated_header.h
  ....


Thanks! It seems checking for the existence of the header is better than my original approach of checking the content.

For managing dependency, cmake exist. Cmake checks if OUTPUT already exists and if timestamp of OUTPUT is greater than timestamp of DEPENDS-encies.
